# CommandMatchers in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

What are commandMatchers in Selenium RollUp? Kindly explain with an example.

This is the code :

```
    var manager = new RollupManager();
    manager.addRollupRule({
        name: 'check_for_syntax_errors',
        description: 'Check for PHP syntax errors, notices, warnings.',
        args: [],
        commandMatchers: [],
        getExpandedCommands: function(args) {
            var commands = [];

            commands.push({
                command: 'assertNotText',
                target: '//body',
                value: '*Notice: Undefined*'
            });
     return commands;
}
```

});

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please check whether you correctly tagged the question.

Comment: Little vague of a question. Check out this link: http://sanjitmohanty.com/2012/07/06/using-the-rollup-feature-of-selenium/